# Check Login with cURL

Tags: php, curl, authentication, passwords

I need to code a PHP script that return "VALID" OR "INVALID PARAMETERS"

- Form URL: http://www.gpsyeah.com/Login.aspx
- Account: istartekdemo
- Password: 123456

  ```
  <?php
  $url = 'http://www.gpsyeah.com/Login.aspx';
  $postfields = array(
  'txtUserName' => 'istartekdemo',
  'txtAccountPassword' => '123456',
  'btnLoginAccount' => '1'
  );

  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);

  $return = curl_exec($curl);
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($return);
  echo '</pre>';
  curl_close($curl);

  if (!preg_match('#Incorrect#i', $return))
  {
  echo 'VALID';
  }
      else
  {
  echo 'INVALID';
  }
  ?>
  ```

**Error notification are displayed with Javascript:Alert. So how can i check login remotely ?**

Comment: Ask a site owner for an API to log in. Or just put your hands off that site. We have CAPTCHAS spoiled our experience with whole internet only thanks to such "remote logins".

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a little:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.gpsyeah.com/Login.aspx';
$postfields = array(
'txtUserName' => 'istartekdemo',
'txtAccountPassword' => '123456',
'btnLoginAccount' => '1'
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);

$return = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if (!preg_match('#loginFaild#i', $return))
{
echo 'VALID';
}
    else
{
echo 'INVALID';
}

?>
```

If you look on the source code of the original site http://www.gpsyeah.com/Login.aspx , when your auth fail, in the code it shows this on line 180:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
loginFaild()//]]>
</script>
</form>
```

Now the script shows the message INVALID.